# How to make App Content Scrollable in Vuetify?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I want my vuetify application content (not the navigation or toolbar) to be scrollable horizontally and vertically to reveal a large grid (much like an iframe or frameset would):
https://cawoodm.github.io/powowshell/ide/

[image]

The main grid is rather large (9x9 200px squares + padding) and the requirements are:

- The content area (yellow) should use all the remaining width and height of the screen (max-height: 100% not working like I think it should)
- The user should be able to scroll that (yellow) content area (see pink scrollbars) to reveal the entire grid

The problem is I only get a vertical scrollbar along the entire height of my window (which I don't want) and, when I scroll that to the bottom I get my horizontal scrollbar (albeit grayed out).

I've hacked together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cawoodm/pen/VOzKWV) which kind of shows the problem but ultimately I'd like the corrections required to the URL demo linked above.

**HTML**

```html
    <v-content >
        <v-layout fill-height fill-width>
          <div id="scroll">
            <div id="grid">81 200x200px blocks go here...
            </div>
          </div>
        </v-layout>
    </v-content>
```

**CSS**

```css
#scroll {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}
#grid {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Ive just get the similar question for my app (how to scroll the v-content). Did you find any proper solution? Thanks!

Comment: No solution sorry!

Comment: ive came up with this ugly solution:     appHeightCss() {
      let appHeight = this.$vuetify.application.top + this.$vuetify.application.footer + 24
      return {
        maxHeight: `calc(100vh - ${appHeight}px)`,
        overflowY: 'auto'
      }
    }  // here i use Vuetify exposed app parameters to calculate height explicitly. 24px is scrolls and paddings